# I'm trying to find the degree of Symmetry of string but my output is coming to be zero

Tags: c++, recursion

The code below is supposed to calculate the degree of symmetry of the given string i used recursion for doing this and my output is always 0 for perfectly symmetrical letters like AAAA

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
int count=0;

void sym(int n,string a)
{
    int mid=(n)/2;
    char ch1[20];
    char ch2[20];
    for(int i=0;i<mid;i++)
    ch1[i]=a[i];
    for(int i=mid;i<n;i++)
    ch2[i-mid]=a[i];
    while(mid!=0)
    {
    if(!strcmp(ch1,ch2))
    {
        count++;
        sym(mid,a);
    }
    else
    break;
    }   
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    string a;
    cout<<"Enter the Size of 2^n : ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter the String : ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    sym(n,a);
    cout<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

The expected result for AAAA should be 2 --> AA-AA and then A-A

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing the char vector and thus probably comparing a lot of garbage that is making it diverge and amount to 0.

Note that due to this, it always breaks the `while`, otherwise it would hang there, as you pass mid by copy and never alter it, which would make it always greater than 0.

You'd be better off replacing the `for` loops to create the substrings by `substr()` calls and the `while` for an `if`:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
int count=0;

void sym(int n,string a)
{
    int mid=(n)/2;
    string ch1 = a.substr(0, mid - 1);
    string ch2 = a.substr(mid, npos);
    if (mid != 0 && ch1.compare(ch2) == 0)
    {
        count++;
        sym(mid, a);
    }   
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    string a;
    cout<<"Enter the Size of 2^n : ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter the String : ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    sym(n,a);
    cout<<count;
    return 0;
}
```